# How to get an id in a datatable and show twig variable inside a datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, modal-dialog, twig

I have a DataTable and want to get an item id to display more information about the item in a modal. Im using twig and dont know how to get the item id and how to display the other information in that modal window using twig.

Datatable

```
<td>
    <a href='#ModalInfo' class="btn" data-toggle="modal" title='info'>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-info text-warning" data-target="#ModalInfo"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCentral" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="TituloModalCentralizado">Aditional information</h5>
                </button>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Responsible: {{alerta.resp}}</p>
            <p>Investment: {{alerta.investment}}</p>
        </div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ModalInfo').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#meuInput').trigger('focus')
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your modals have the same `id`. This is invalid and will cause problems in showing the correct modal window. You should append the `id` of your "`alerta`"

You should also place one modal per "`alerta`"

```
{% for alerta in alertas %}
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalInfo{{ alerta.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCentral" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Aditional information</h5>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Responsible: {{alerta.resp}}</p>
            <p>Investment: {{alerta.investment}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<td>
    <a href='#ModalInfo{{ alerta.id }}' class="btn" data-toggle="modal" title='info'>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-info text-warning" data-target="#ModalInfo{{ alerta.id }}"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

---

Sidenote: The HTML of your modal is invalid...

Comment: Tks DarkBee ! I found the problem with your help !! I used the script: $('#ModalInfo{{alerta.id}}').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  alert("modal open");
  $('#meuInput').trigger('focus')